# Make SaveFileDialog to NOT create a test file in the directory selected by user

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

Our users sometimes work with the directories where the deletion of files is not allowed. (Both the file system permissions *Delete* and *Delete subfolders and files* are denied). We use the System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog to allow user to select the directory and provide the file name to save their data.

If user browses to the directory with no delete permissions, they get the following error message when press Save button of the SaveFileDialog:

> You don't have permission to modify files in this network location. 
>   Contact the administrator per permission to make these changes.

In addition to this unwanted message, when user presses Cancel in the dialog, the zero-length file with the name that user specified is left behind in the directory.

This all happens because by default the SaveFileDialog probes the directory by creating a zero-length file in it. When the probing is done it deletes the temporary file. In our case it cannot delete (because the file system does not allow deletion), and the whole probing is regarded by the dialog a failure, and the error message is shown to the user.

What is the easiest way to switch off this directory verification step? I know that other standard checks causing messages can be switched off with the properties of SaveFileDialog (i.e. CheckFileExist property) but it seems that not this one.

Comment: Have you tried the newer file dialogs (CommonSaveFileDialog) ? They are accessible through the Windows API Code Pack : https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory` property of the dialog to the value of a directory you know the user has write access to before displaying it.

Comment: Users have _Write_ access the the directory of interest. They do not have permission to _Delete_ in this directory and they are willing to live with this restriction. In other words they are OK to be able to only create files in the directory. When they want to delete, they will need to ask another person with higher privileges to review their decision and delete if approved.

Comment: So as per my comment except substitute "write access" for "delete access"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the [`SaveFileDialog.FileOK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. It has the `CancelEventArgs` as the second argument, so you can verify the desired directory is accessible for deletion and set `e.Cancel = true`, if not.
Sample code:

```
using (SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    dlg.FileOk += (sender, e) => e.Cancel = !DirectoryIsGood(dlg.FileName);
    dlg.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Please note that you need to create the `DirectoryIsGood(filename)` method, which should check the directory by a given `filename`.
*I'm not sure that this event is triggered before the `SaveFileDialog` internal checks, but it makes sense you to try. Maybe it'll help.*

Answer (score 0):

By default, the dialog box creates a zero-length test file to determine whether a new file can be created in the selected directory. To prevent the creation of this test file, set the OFN_NOTESTFILECREATE flag.